# Retrieve data from FireStore

Tags: flutter, dart

In firestore I have collection 'products' which is displayed with `StreamBuilder` in `DataTable`.

```
StreamBuilder<List<Product>>(
    stream: ProductService().products,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('name'),
            ),
          ],
          rows: snapshot.data.map((products) {
            return DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(products.name),
                onTap: () => showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => ProductDetails()
                )
              ),
            ]);
          }).toList(),
```

my class:

```
    class ProductService {
  var dbTimeKey = DateTime.now();
  var formatDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  

  final CollectionReference _firestore =
      Firestore.instance.collection("products");

  List<Product> _productList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Product(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        price: doc.data['price'] ?? '0',
        category: doc.data['category'] ?? '',
        quantity: doc.data['quantity'] ?? '0',
        date: doc.data['date'] ?? '',
        image: doc.data['image'] ?? '',
        isActive: doc.data['isActive'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Product>> get products {
    return _firestore.snapshots().map(_productList);
  }

  Product productDetailsFromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Product(
      name: snapshot.data['name'],
      price: snapshot.data['price'],
      category: snapshot.data['category'],
      quantity: snapshot.data['quantity'],
      date: snapshot.data['date'],
      image: snapshot.data['image'],
      isActive: snapshot.data['isActive'],
    );
  }

  Stream<Product> get productDetails {
    return _firestore.document().snapshots().map(productDetailsFromSnap);
  }
}
```

I want to display product details in `showDialog` when I tap on my product name.
This is how I try to do:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<Product>(
    stream: ProductService().productDetails,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        Product productDetails = snapshot.data;
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            child: Form(
              key: _formProductDetails,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                      initialValue: productDetails.name,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return Text('error');
      }
    });}
```

When I tap on product name I return text widget.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to display product details after tap in datatable

Comment: So you want to QUERY all products from firestore show them in a list then when you Tap on an element it displays a product details page??

Comment: yes i want it that way, but i am stuck how to displays it!